# ReactNative + NodeJS - Need of Socket.io for simple chat?

Tags: node.js, react-native, api, express, chat

Am developing a mobile app for Students and Teachers to interact(one to one). So the scenario is, sometimes, Teacher would give a homework to the Student. And if the Student can ask a couple of questions if he has any doubts regarding the homework.

So am displaying the WhatsApp like chat window for the Student & Teacher (in ReactNative mobile app).

And am using NodeJS, Express and MongoDB for the server(API) side. When a Student wants to send a message or the Teacher want to send a message, they type in the TextInput and on pressing the send button, the app will make an API call to save this message in the database. I have implemented that and no problem.

And when Student or Teacher opens up the message screen, an API call is made to pull all the messages and is displayed. I have done that too.

But my doubt is, how should I ping the server if the Student or the Teacher is in the same screen (say Student named "A" viewing the chat screen of Teacher named "T"). Both parties won't be online always. So this won't be a chat intensive app.

Should I use Socket.io to do the chat implementation or should I just ping the server at a certain interval if the Student/Teacher is in the same screen? If latter, do I have to put the API call code (to check for new messages) inside the `useEffect()` ? Am a bit confused here

Comment: For a chat system, socket is preferred always as it will be fast and much more efficient

Comment: @DeekshithHegde so do I have to create different NodeJS app only for the Chats or I can use the Socket.io along with my existing serverside application? Also, do I have to send the auth token together with each message (like I do in each API call now) ?

Comment: You can use your existing application provided your existing application is not serverless. For the auth token, my suggestion is you will have to pass a auth token and verify it from your db when establishing a socket connection and post that it's not needed

Comment: You need to save all your chat data here so your current approach is fine. Use socket io to check if both are in the same screen and to refresh messages when someone sends it.